# Bisection root method in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am new in MATLAB and I want to know why my code for the bisection method doesn't run , this is the code:

```
function [ r ] = bisection1( f1, a, b, N, eps_step, eps_abs )
    % Check that that neither end-point is a root
    % and if f(a) and f(b) have the same sign, throw an exception.

    if ( f1(a) == 0 )
    r = a;
    return;
    elseif ( f1(b) == 0 )
    r = b;
    return;
    elseif ( f1(a) * f1(b) > 0 )
        error( 'f(a) and f(b) do not have opposite signs' );
    end

    % We will iterate N times and if a root was not
    % found after N iterations, an exception will be thrown.

    for k = 1:N
        % Find the mid-point
        c = (a + b)/2;

        % Check if we found a root or whether or not
        % we should continue with:
        %          [a, c] if f(a) and f(c) have opposite signs, or
        %          [c, b] if f(c) and f(b) have opposite signs.

        if ( f1(c) == 0 )
            r = c;
            return;
        elseif ( f1(c)*f1(a) < 0 )
            b = c;
        else
            a = c;
        end

        % If |b - a| < eps_step, check whether or not
        %       |f(a)| < |f(b)| and |f(a)| < eps_abs and return 'a', or
        %       |f(b)| < eps_abs and return 'b'.

        if ( b - a < eps_step )
            if ( abs( f1(a) ) < abs( f1(b) ) && abs( f1(a) ) < eps_abs )
                r = a;
                return;
            elseif ( abs( f1(b) ) < eps_abs )
                r = b;
                return;
            end
        end
    end

    error( 'the method did not converge' );
end
```

And I defined

```
function y=f1(x)
    y=x^3+x-3;
end
```

In another script but when I type `bisection1(f1,1,2,100,10^-6,10^-6)` it doesn't run.

Can you help me to complete this task please?

Comment: You should get back to the MATLAB book you got this code from. `f1` is now a function as well and requires input arguments, which means you cannot pass it to `bisection1` as an argument.

Comment: Right :) but then I tried bisection1(f1(x),1,2,100,10^-6,10^-6) and it didn't worked.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the only thing that is wrong is your command to run the script. Because you defined `f1` in a file, you cannot supply the function name into your `bisection1` function. You must provide a *handle*. To do this simply type:

`bisection1(@f1,1,2,100,10^-6,10^-6)`

Notice the '@' symbol. If you define `f1` in the command prompt like this:
`f1 = @(x) x.^3+x-3;`

then you can simply pass it in as you've done above.

Read more about the `@` symbol here : [function handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html)

Comment: Just to clarify, `@` defines an [anonymous function](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) in MATLAB.

Comment: Actually it does not. `@` is simply a function handle. Using it like I did in my answer, or like on the page you showed, creates a *handle* to an anonymous function, but it also is a function handle to named functions. Notice the first example on the page you linked says "create a *handle* to an anonymous function". I've updated my answer to include a link on function handles.

Comment: Good explanation, cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot :), but why the down vote?